# Storage::move giving “File not found at path:”

Tags: laravel, laravel-storage

I am trying to move an image from one folder into another folder by using:

```
Storage::move(storage_path('app/public/temporary/').$imageName, storage_path('app/public/profilePic/'.$imageName));
```

But when i run it gave me the error:

> *File not found at path: home/vagrant/code/avida/storage/app/public/temporary/5bfb7272e9dc9.download.jpeg*

i google and found the following solution:

```
Storage::disk('local')->move(storage_path('app/public/temporary/').$imageName, storage_path('app/public/profilePic/'.$imageName));
```

but then it gave another error:

> *Method 'disk' not found in \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage*

Can anyone please help me how can i move this file ?
Thank you

Comment: Did you link storage? php artisan storage:link

Comment: yes i did, but i dont know why the generated storage link is red color and mentioned broken link

Comment: Did you try to change storage_path to public_path in filesystem and check?

Comment: Check loaded class in top of controller. Should be `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`

Answer (score 0):

Storage class operate in storage directory so there is no need to use storage_path() helper.

Change your code to the one below:

```
Storage::move('public/temporary/'.$imageName, 'public/profilePic/'.$imageName);
```

I hope that helps :)